# Using google translate voice api with phantomjs

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, web-crawler

Thank you for showing interest to my question.
I'm trying to use voice API of google translate by selenium.
My code works fine when using firefox web driver for selenium.
[image: Google Translation]

But, when I try to use PhantomJS, I get ElementNotVisibleException. So I took screen shot of PhantomJS and checked it, and I found that there is no button for voice API.
[image: Google Translation with PhantomJS]

Does phantomJS not support google voice API originally?
or Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Include some code.